# Can't change pivot on gameObject in unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Everything was fine till all gameObjects stoped to see pivots from their sprites
in sprite they have pivot in the bottom, and gameObject has sprite sort point set to pivot, but all they show and act as pivot is in the center

[[gameObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSxDn.png)]
[[sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfUkn.png)]

Why could this happen and how to fix it?

I have tryed create gameObjects again and reasign pivot, also reimported sprite file, but nothing changed

Comment: Could you add more information on what you're trying to achieve and why you decided to use another sort point than the center please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like tool handle position is set to center. You can change it from the top left part of the scene view from center to pivot.

[image: Tool handle position dropdown]

Comment: Thanks for this advice!
But it only changed how pivot is seen in scene, but sorting layers is still working wrong, as pivot still in center

Answer (score 0):

I have found couse of problem - it was render settings, after shifting to new pipeline assets render my setting for transparency sort mode was changed, I set them againg and it works as it was